# OpenSSL: Unable to create SSL_CTX * using SSL_CTX_new()

Tags: c, linux, ssl, openssl

Following the instructions on [page](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-openssl/index.html) , I am trying to use openSSL to connect client/server in secure manner.

I am not able to create the SSL_CTX as follows:

```
 /* OpenSSL headers */

 #include "openssl/bio.h"
 #include "openssl/ssl.h"
 #include "openssl/err.h"

 int main()
 {

       /* Initializing OpenSSL */

       SSL_load_error_strings();
       ERR_load_BIO_strings();
       OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();

       SSL_CTX * ctx = SSL_CTX_new(SSLv23_client_method());

       .....
  }
```

The ctx reference always turns out to be NULL. Can anyone please tell what step am I missing?

Thanks.

**Update**

On checking error, the message was

```
 Error: library has no ciphers
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I used the following call at start of main() function:

```
SSL_library_init();
```

Solution found at: [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=622297)

Comment: Also note that you can have this same error if you use the wrong argument to `SSL_CTX_new()`. I had found some code that used `SSLv2_client_method()`. It compiled and ran, but was getting a NULL `ctx` value.