# Library has no ciphers available

Tags: c++, macos, ssl, openssl

Im currently trying to create a HTTPS connection on my Mac using C++ and XCode.

the Code is rather simple:

```
SSL_load_error_strings();
ERR_load_BIO_strings();
OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();

SSL * ssl;
BIO * bio;
SSL_CTX * ctx = SSL_CTX_new(SSLv23_client_method());

std::string host = host_IPv4 + ":443"; // host_IPv4 given as std::string

if(ctx == NULL){

    std::cout << ERR_reason_error_string(ERR_get_error()) << std::endl;

}

int load_error = SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations(ctx, "/path/to/ca.pem", NULL);
```

Now i have all this in a function and pass host_IPv4 to it. The function is called fro the main.cpp.

My problem is that ctx is always NULL and the error i get is

> library has no ciphers

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10163968/openssl-unable-to-create-ssl-ctx-using-ssl-ctx-new) that i should run

```
SSL_library_init();
```

before any other SSL calls, but that sadly did not resolve anything. Still getting the same error no matter where i put that code in.

Im on OS X 10.10 using XCode 6.2 and libssl 0.9.8 and libcrypto 0.9.8 (they where preinstalled i guess).

Anyone has an idea?

Comment: Coomon please im searching Google the whole day now but can only find "Use SSL_library_init()", but thats not working..

Comment: Be careful of those [C++ static objects](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/static-init-order.html). They can get out of hand quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Okay got it.. was my fault:

i defined ctx as a global variable, that way it happened before the init() of SSL.