# MariaDB [ERROR] WSREP: context: library has no ciphers

Tags: mariadb, galera

I have a mariadb/galera problem.

I updated my OpenSuse tumbleweed server.
I think the relevant changes are:

OpenSSL 1.0.x -> OpenSSL 1.1.x 
mariadb-10.1.25 -> mariadb-10.2.13 
galera 3.23.20 -> galera 3.23.20 (not changed)

After the update, the mariadb server didn't start anymore with this error:

```
2018-04-06 13:12:13 139995648866240 [Note] WSREP: wsrep_load(): Galera 3.23(rac090bc) by Codership Oy <info@codership.com> loaded successfully.
2018-04-06 13:12:13 139995648866240 [Note] WSREP: CRC-32C: using hardware acceleration.
2018-04-06 13:12:13 139995648866240 [Note] WSREP: Found saved state: c5779b6f-035a-11e7-89db-52dab15b6e6b:34767967, safe_to_bootstrap: 0
2018-04-06 13:12:13 139995648866240 [Note] WSREP: Passing config to GCS: base_dir = /srv/mysql/; base_host = x.x.x.x; base_port = 4567; cert.log_conflicts = no; debug = no; evs.auto_evict = 0; evs.delay_margin = PT1S; evs.delayed_keep_period = PT30S; evs.inactive_check_period = PT0.5S; evs.inactive_timeout = PT15S; evs.join_retrans_period = PT1S; evs.max_install_timeouts = 3; evs.send_window = 4; evs.stats_report_period = PT1M; evs.suspect_timeout = PT5S; evs.user_send_window = 2; evs.view_forget_timeout = PT24H; gcache.dir = /srv/mysql/; gcache.keep_pages_size = 0; gcache.mem_size = 0; gcache.name = /srv/mysql//galera.cache; gcache.page_size = 128M; gcache.recover = no; gcache.size = 128M; gcomm.thread_prio = ; gcs.fc_debug = 0; gcs.fc_factor = 1.0; gcs.fc_limit = 16; gcs.fc_master_slave = no; gcs.max_packet_size = 64500; gcs.max_throttle = 0.25; gcs.recv_q_hard_limit = 9223372036854775807; gcs.recv_q_soft_limit = 0.25; gcs.sync_donor = no; gmcast.segment = 0; gmcast.version = 0; pc.announce_timeout = PT3S; pc.checksum = false; pc.ignore_quoru
2018-04-06 13:12:13 139995648866240 [Note] WSREP: MemPool(SlaveTrxHandle): hit ratio: 0, misses: 0, in use: 0, in pool: 0
2018-04-06 13:12:13 139995648866240 [Note] WSREP: Flushing memory map to disk...
2018-04-06 13:12:13 139995648866240 [ERROR] WSREP: context: library has no ciphers
2018-04-06 13:12:13 139995648866240 [ERROR] WSREP: wsrep::init() failed: 7, must shutdown
2018-04-06 13:12:13 139995648866240 [ERROR] Aborting
```

As far as i understand it, it's a problem with the openSSL library and that he couldn't read the supported ciphers. (Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10163968/openssl-unable-to-create-ssl-ctx-using-ssl-ctx-new))

But i haven't enabled ssl for wsrep. Could i tell mariadb/galera somehow not even to try to enable ssl?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded the source for the libgalera_smm.so  from the [galera website](http://galeracluster.com/downloads/#downloads).

I had to rewrite some lines in the file "SConstruct" to make it python3 compatible.

After compiling the source, wsrep works fine again.